# Cant connect to teradata sql server through python, works fine through teradata sql assistant

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, teradata, pyodbc

I have a problem connecting to a Teradata SQL Server through Python, even though it works fine through Teradata SQL Assistant

Options when connecting in Teradata SQL Assistant are:
Server: xx1,
Data Source Name: xx2,
Mechanism: LDAP,
User Name: *,
Password: *,
Session Character Set: ASCII,
Port: 1025

Im Trying to connect through Python using Pyodbc with the following connection string:
pyodbc.connect('Driver={Teradata}; DBCName=xx1; Uid=*; Pwd=*; Authentication=LDAP; Database=xx2')

I'm getting the error message: "WSA E ConnRefused: The Teradata server is not accepting connections (10061) (SQLDriverConnect)". This is even though I have no problems getting a connection using Teradata SQL Assistant.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't DBCName === Data Source Name?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, that's my mistake. It works when setting Server=xx1 and DBCName=xx2 - thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reinstalling the pyodbc package and connect again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].